# Getting null value during calling Connection object in separate JSP file

Tags: java, class, jsp, jdbc, database-connection

I Have created one Connection class and in that defined one method , so that everytime i have to create connection i just call that method . In seaparate JSP file i am try to call that getConnection method but getting null value it means Connection is not created , but if i am creating main method and if in that i am caling getConnection method then i am getting the object reference

```
    package com.Tech.Blog.Helper;
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectionProvider {
    private static Connection con;   
    public static Connection getConnection()   //Created one method which will return con
    {
        try {                   
        if (con == null) {    
                //driver class load 
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                //create a connection
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youtube";
                String username="root";
                String password="Root_5";
                con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;

    }






 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="com.Tech.Blog.Helper.ConnectionProvider"%>
<!-- importing the package -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>JSP page</title>

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  <!-- Linking of css to jsp -->
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     <%

         Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getConnection(); 
     %>
     <%= con %>    <!--getting null for this-->


<!-- In expression tags -->

 <!-- JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   <!-- Linking of js to jsp -->

</body>
</html>
```